# How to compare between UTC time string (ISO 8601)

Tags: c++, c, datetime

I am having some issues to compare between time strings which are in UTC format.

For example:

```
string1 = "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00"
string2 = "2000-07-17T20:20:30+01:00"
```

My goal is to find out which time is latest.

I have surfed through internet and found about `mktime();` But example strings are in normal format, on the other hand my string is in ISO8601 format.

I am looking for a solution which is compatible with windows and linux.

I would really appriciate some help.

Comment: Convert from string to broken down time first with `strptime`. Then you can use the `mktime` examples you have found.

Comment: There are very few things in C++ that can be accomplished simply by finding a function in the C++ library that does everything. If this is a programming assignment, I'm confident that the intended solution involves writing your own string parser that extracts the individual values from the string, and compares them in a meaningful way using appropriate logic that you will need to figure out and write the code for.

Comment: As the strings are formatted in the order of year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds with fixed width, string comparison works such as `int result = strcmp(string1, string2);`.

Comment: @tshiono Good point. Though it should also be pointed out that it will only work if the time offset is the same.

Comment: @kaylum thank you for the comment. Exactly. The time offset is crucial for the comparison.

Comment: Please don't tag different languages. Tag the language you are using only.

Comment: Do you have to deal with different time zone offsets?  Both values are in the same time zone, so the string comparison is quite adequate — one of the beauties of the ISO 8601 notation.  If you have different time zone values, then you have to do more work.  POSIX provides [`strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) as the scanning counterpart to standard C's
[`strftime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html).  You may or may not find `strptime()` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To most easily take into account the UTC offset field, C++20 `<chrono>` is the way to go.  If you have C++11/14/17, there exists a [free, open-source, header-only preview](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) of this part of C++20 that can be used.  And it works on both Linux and Windows.  If you're using C, this easy solution is not available.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    string string1 = "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00";
    string string2 = "2000-07-17T20:20:30+01:00";
    sys_seconds t1, t2;

    string format = "%FT%T%Ez";

    istringstream in{string1};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    in >> parse(format, t1);
    in.clear();
    in.str(string2);
    in >> parse(format, t2);

    if (t1 > t2)
        cout << string1 << " is later than " << string2 << '\n';
    else if (t2 > t1)
        cout << string2 << " is later than " << string1 << '\n';
    else
        cout << string1 << " is the same time as " << string2 << '\n';
}
```

Above is the C++20 solution.

- The type `sys_seconds` is a seconds-precision UTC timestamp.  When this is parsed into with `parse`, the parsed time is considered as local time, and modified by the parsed UTC offset before being assigned to the `sys_seconds` argument.  The `E` modifier in `%Ez` instructs `parse` to look for the `:` in the offset.  `%z` (without the `E`) looks for an offset of the form `hhmm`.
- I've set the `failbit` in the stream so that any parse errors result in a noisy exception.  If you would rather check for `in.fail()` manually, omit setting `failbit`.
- Once `t1` and `t2` are parsed into, they can be compared just like arithmetic types.
- If you need to use the [free, open-source, header-only preview](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), just add `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;` to the above program.

If you can be assured that the UTC offsets are always equal, then a simple string comparison is sufficient:

```
if (string1 > string2)
    cout << string1 << " is later than " << string2 << '\n';
else if (string2 > string1)
    cout << string2 << " is later than " << string1 << '\n';
else
    cout << string1 << " is the same time as " << string2 << '\n';
```

In C (and if the UTC offsets can be different), you will have to parse the offsets and subtract them from the local times manually.